# Update UI from callback methode (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, ui-thread

I have an Event Handler that calls a method (`onLobbyParticipantAdded`) after the event `lobbyParicipantAdded` arrived.

In the method `onLobbyPaticipantAdded`, it always ends if it want to change something in the UI.

**Here is my code**

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        EventHandler.Add("lobbyParticipantAdded", onLobbyParticipantAdded);
    }

    public void onLobbyParticipantAdded(dynamic obj)
    {
        LobbyParticipantAdded l = new LobbyParticipantAdded();
        l = obj;

        SC1.Text = l.displayname;
        Ready1.Text = "Ready";
    }
```

Does someone know this problem? And know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to execute the UI related code within the main thread (like the example below)

```
    public void onLobbyParticipantAdded(dynamic obj)
    {
         LobbyParticipantAdded l = new LobbyParticipantAdded();
         l = obj;

         this.InvokeOnMainThread (() => 
         {
             SC1.Text = l.displayname;
             Ready1.Text = "Ready";  
         });       
    }
```

Comment: For reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/ios-ui/ui-thread/